# Roblox Lua Give LocalPlayer weapon doesn't work,

Tags: lua, roblox

My code: https://justpaste.it/87evk

```
local original = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):FindFirstChild("CloneSmoke")
 
local tool = script.Parent
local copy = original:Clone()
 
tool.Activated:Connect(function()
print("Running...")
local sound = script.Parent.Sound
 
copy.Parent = script.Parent.Handle
sound:Play()
wait(3)
tool:Destroy()
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local weapon = game.ReplicatedStorage.Jutsus.Momoshiki["Momoshikis Sword"]
local w2 = weapon:Clone()
w2.Parent = plr.Backpack
end)
```

Idk what i have to do here to get the Player and give him a Weapon.I tried much but i dont get the right Soloution.
It were nice wenn you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make sure this is in a LocalScript

Also change `local original = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):FindFirstChild("CloneSmoke")` to `local original = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("CloneSmoke")` This is because the script loads faster than items in the game, so chances are, the sword hasn't loaded into the game by the time the script runs; the script won't work if it doesn't find the object you are trying to reference.